# HTML Tag Isolation

Tags: vb.net, html-agility-pack

Using the htmlagilitypack how can I isolate the tag I am searching for.

The application is to parse through the source code of a certain website to find a tag that has text that is going to be extracted. as shown in the below

```
            <div> this is the text i want to extract</div>
```

I have tried RegEx and used some string manipulation but to no use.

Comment: This `<\tag>` thing looks like incorrect HTML. Is this really what you're looking for?

Comment: apologoies should have been <\div>.

Comment: This is still strange :-) A correct HTML would be `</div>`.

Comment: Lols recorrected again! Any ideas on the question?

Comment: XPATH could get it with `//div`. See this similar answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13147749/html-agility-pack-with-vb-net-parsing however, just one div may not be discriminant enough. If you have the full page or an url, we can help more.

Comment: The general idea is to go to a url called "www.answers.com" type in a question (which then changes the url) then get the source code of the URL into a textbox, which i have done up to this point then to highlight a tag from start to finish, including the text within it and copy to a textbox. here is the tag start                     <div class="answer_text" id="editorText"> Here is the text i want extracted </div> en of tag

Answer (score 0):

When you have a good discriminant (which you pointed out in the comment), for example a CLASS attribute, XPATH is an easy way to query the HTML DOM, like this:

```
   Dim question As String = "what time is it"
   Dim web As New HtmlWeb
   Console.WriteLine(web.Load(("http://wiki.answers.com/Q/" & question)).DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//div[@class='answer_text']").InnerText.Trim)
```